# How to interpret this CNN architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

[image]

How does this CNN architecture work from an input layer to the first convolution layer? hx98 are input matrix dimensions, is n the number of channels or the number of inputs?

It doesn't seem like n is the number of channels because 25 is the number of feature maps and their dimensions do not indicate they are two channels.

However if n is the number of inputs and matrices are single channel, I haven't found a single CNN architecture anywhere that takes multiple input matrices and convolute them together. Most example convolute them seperately and then concatenate.

In my example, n is 2, one is matrix with BER values and another with connection line-rate values.

What mistake am I making? How does this CNN work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a programming question as defined in the [help/on-topic]. You might have better luck on [datascience.se] or [stats.se].

Answer (score 0):

- In CNN the image pixels with height and width are multiplied with the
  kernel weights of the convolution layer and are added to create a
  feature map.
- The kernel will pass through all the channels of the
  image (3 channels for RGB, 1 channel for GreyScale) based on the
  strides defined in the convolution layer.
- After the convolution, the size of the image is reduced.
- To get the same output dimension as the input dimension, you need to add padding. Padding consists of adding
  the right number of rows and columns on each side of the matrix. For
  details, please refer to this
  [documentation](https://www.guru99.com/convnet-tensorflow-image-classification.html).
  Thank You.